# How to display different (live) elements in a grid layout?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

What I'd like to do is create a grid layout that has multiple live components. I'm trying to implement this layout, and am struggling to figure out the best way of doing it.

The 4 main elements of the grid layout:

1. Imageview (the green bar). It changes colours to green/ red/ or yellow, depending on the delay.
2. Textview (the title). The title changes based on an update call. It's the recommended title.
3. Textview (Delay). Will be a string with the delay status (either No delay or 30 Minutes)
4. Imageview (background for delay text). Will never change.

After reading about this on StackOverflow, an embedded grid layout seems to be the best choice, but I haven't seen a good way of incorporating different elements (that are set every new "Update"/ pageload) into a Grid Layout without having multiple views set for each element.

Here is the picture I want to implement (http://imgur.com/8TrFvl8)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using a [recycler view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead